# Can CCLeaner (and similar programs) actually fix stuff?

Tags: windows-registry, ccleaner

THe way I get it, CCLeaner works by removing "dangling" registry entries. Its authors claim that this is supposed to improve the system's performance.

However, I can see that CCleaner is widely recommended against. The harms of having unused registry entries are negligible; however, the dangers of mistakingly removing a needed entry (or arbitrarily messing with system-wide / other programs' entries) are real.  It is reported that frequently CCleaner BREAKS stuff rather than fixing it.

Microsoft recommends against using such programs: [1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-files/registry-cleaners/5311416e-e8f5-460b-981c-925abf7c22bd) [2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2563254/microsoft-support-policy-for-the-use-of-registry-cleaning-utilities) [3](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-performance/is-there-a-microsoft-licensed-registry-cleaner-i/b03cd0ad-a92c-41b2-9bf0-b7be06c43047?auth=1)

However! There are still people around who keep recommending the use of CCleaner. They say, they have yet to see CCleaner breaking stuff. They say, they have many times fixed errors in different programs thanks to CCleaner.

For this reason, may I ask you:

- In what cases may it be recommended to use a registry cleaning software?
- In what cases can it be presumed that the chances of such software fixing things are higher than the chances that it will break stuff?
- In what cases is it recommended against using registry cleaning software, as it will likely only break stuff?
- Or is it recommended to simply cleanly reistall broken programs or even the whole system in case of failures, as it will likely yield better results than letting a fishy software arbitrarily mess with an already broken installation?

Comment: CCleaner is useful when needed and used appropriately, and cleaning the registry is only one minor feature in it. cleaning up temporary and junk files is its primary purpose.  I've used the registry cleaner occasionally when I have traces of an application that didn't disappear on uninstall or didn't even provide an uninstaller, that said, it should not be used blindly, and it won't "fix" problems in a general sense, unless that problem is that there is something there that shouldn't be,

Comment: I personally use CCleaner (infrequently) rather than other registry cleaners, at least partly because it always prompts to create a registry backup, which I always do. And because its temp file cleaner is quite a bit faster and more thorough than the built-in Disk Cleanup. But, for average people, if they ask me about running reg cleaners, I tell them not to for the same reasons you note above: If it breaks something, they'll have no idea how to fix it, and the odds are that cleaning the registry won't fix the sorts of problems they're having.

Comment: Registry cleaners usefulness are overstated.  The registry is designed in such a way that orphaned registry keys do not actually have a performance impact.  Register cleaners are basically the electronic version of snake oil, and the companies that make them, are the snake oil salesmen.  There is a reason there isn't a built-in tool, to "clean" the registry, it's not required.

Comment: Guys who are voting to close my question as "opinion based" - HOW can it be opinion based? Whether or not stuff is broken is not opinion based, but objective, I believe? Whether or not a given class of software is helpful at fixing stuff / threatens to break stuff is again objective?

Comment: The thing is, fix-it utilities are, more often than not, pure snakeoil. And like snakeoil, they can actually be dangerous. As my answer tries to clarify, the general class of registry cleaners are mostly dangerous, and even the honest ones should not be used by regular folk because the potential for difficult-to-repair damage is simply too great. The depth of the answers necessary to fully and completely answer your question is simply too great to work here. The answers that have been posted are basically OK, mostly because they tell you that CCleaner specifically is OK, but don't use it.

Comment: The other thing is, almost every time the word "Can" is used to start a question, the question is worse because of it. "Can" questions only need 1-word answers: yes, no, maybe. Most "can" questions should be "how" questions instead.

Answer (score -1):

My perspective is CCleaner is a great product. But, if you aren't sure what you are doing, best not to do it. True that registry cleaning is not going to make your system blazingly fast. The other stuff it does, such as cleaning up files is helpful too. Can it fix stuff? I guess it is possible, but to me it is a maintenance product to use sparingly. If it helps you learn more as you are working with it, it is worth it. Test machines are very handy in this situation.

Answer (score -2):

Can it fix things? Sure.

Will it fix what is ailing you? Depends, but don't count on it.

Registry Cleaners claim all the benefits of snake oil. CCleaner, thankfully, doesn't, but simply by being a registry cleaner it rides the coattails of those unscrupulous programs that do.

As Jon DeRosier notes, it doesn't speed your computer up. As others here note it doesn't really fix the things people think are wrong with their computers. And I agree with what appears to be the consensus here that average people should not be recommended to use this. When people ask me if they should run a registry cleaner I tell them they are no silver bullet, and the sorts of things they could break by trusting such a program can end up being very difficult to fix.

However, as part of a technicians toolkit, yes, CCleaner is a worthwhile tool to have. The default action of prompting to backup before it cleans is a good safeguard, and its other features are good. Its temp file cleaner is far faster than Disk Cleanup, and it gets programs Disk Cleanup doesnt.

Regarding uninstaller cleanup and fixing, I personally prefer RevoUninstaller. It is also a registry cleaner, but it adds file cleanup, and both these work in service to a system that can observe an uninstaller process and then cleanup things the uninstaller missed or failed to remove.